# Do epic project points expire if current project isn't finished?

Tags: simcity-buildit

Has anybody gotten far enough in the new upgrade of SimCity Build-It to tell if the epic project points expire if you don't finish the epic project on time?

I somehow got stuck with my FIRST one being the Transportation project which requires 80 tokens for the silver tier. I've got 54 to go with only 8 hours left, and I believe it's a pointless crusade. (Not even going to try for gold.) I'm just wondering if I'm going to lose the 26 points I worked so hard to earn if I don't get to 80 by the time the clock runs out.

Comment: As winspear wrote, you lose them but if you add more high-epic-point-value buildings (like university=3) it gets easier. I just finished my first silver and it took me 23 hours...not sure it was worth it but I got it. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will lose the project points I am afraid so before starting another epic project, I'd recommend preparing yourself for some dedicated hours, it gets pretty difficult to produce and source the vast amount of items needed.

Comment: Yes, this is what I noticed this morning. The only thing I hope is that if we ever get to re-do certain projects, that our old points will be there. (Thank goodness I'm on winter break, otherwise I work too many hours in a day to play, what a disappointment!)

Answer (score 0):

I completed my first epic project and finished on the copper. So the building will produce 1 turtle token every day. I haven't received another epic project yet, I don't know if they just appear or if I can choose to star one. But I'd imagine you have to start over again for the next one, I don't think the tokens would carry over.

Comment: It seems to not even generate an entire turtle token a day, only a third of one. False advertising if you ask me!!

Comment: @lemontwist Actually bronze = 1/3 per day. Silver = 1/6 per day...so prepare to be more frustrated as you work harder. ;-)

Answer (score -2):

The countdown is merely a timer, counting down until the building is complete.

Your level at the time of completion determines the token that will be generated.

Comment: That really doesn't answer my question. I had about 30 epic points that didn't go towards an upgrade, and I'm not sure yet if they're totally gone or not. I guess I have to wait until the next epic project starts.